# An impressive fact expressible in Presburger arithmetic?

Tags: logic, arithmetic, model-theory, automated-theorem-proving, presburger-arithmetic

Is there anything expressible in Presburger arithmetic that would seem impressive to students at an undergraduate level?

Comment: I'm already impressed by the fact something called "presburger arithmetic" even exists.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this will impress anybody, but for **fixed** relatively prime $m$ and $n$ the fact that any number divisible by $m$ and $n$ is also divisible by $mn$ is expressible in Presburger arithmetic.

E.g., the assertion "$x$ is divisible by $5$" is expressed by the formula
$$\exists y(x=y+y+y+y+y).$$